# How to show the latest data from sqlite db and animation to see more?

Tags: php, html, database, sqlite, pdo

Hi I want to do that it get the data from the sqlite database to only show the latest one but it show all and make an animation so when scroll on that it shows more one by one

> pls help me and pls don't devote this question I can't ask more questions then I really need help I'm trying to fund from one whole day but didn't find any so I asked as this is a good community
> Code

```
 <?php
 
 $conn = new PDO("sqlite: Review.db");
 $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
 $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM Review ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
 
     while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
         print_r($row['Review']);
     }
     
 ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <title>Social Cabin</title>
</head>

<body>
    <nav>
        <div class="hamburger">
            <div class="line"></div>
            <div class="line"></div>
            <div class="line"></div>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav-links">
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <section id="landing">
        <img src="cabbin.jpeg" id="landing-image">
    <h1>Social Cabin</h1>
  </section>
  <section>
    <div class="join" >
      <h3>Why Should You Join Us?</h3>
      <p>School is the place where we learn to read and write. It is the most crucial place for a student, and it helps us to learn new things. The teachers are always helpful and teach us important things in life. We must always be regular to school as missing classes can lead to problems during exams. Schools teach us how to be consistent, punctual, and obedient. It also makes us better human beings so that we can treat our elders with respect. Most of what we learn is a result of the learning imparted by our teachers.
      </p>
      <section>
      <hr class="fir" >
      <h3 class="about" >About Us</h3>
      <p id="consider" >Considering that the chain’s main draw is high quality food at low prices, it makes sense that customers might question how Trader Joe’s can afford to charge less than other brands. This short explanation answers that question, and it’s easy to see how it could be very effective at drawing new customers to their local store.</p>
    <img src="team.jpg" class="team "  >
    </section>
    <section class="all" >
   <div class="slidercontainer">  
   <div class="showSlide fade">  
   <img src="1.png" />  

   </div>  
   <div class="showSlide fade">  
   <img src="3.png"/>  
   
   </div>  
   
   <div class="showSlide fade">  
   <img src="2.png"/>  
   </div>  
   <div class="showSlide fade">  
   <img src="3.png"/>  
 
   </div>  
   <!-- Navigation arrows -->  
   <a class="left" onclick="nextSlide(-1)">❮</a>  
   <a class="right" onclick="nextSlide(1)">❯</a>  
   </div>  
   
   </section>
    </section>
    </div>
</section>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, what you need is to create a 'load more' button that will load more data when pressed, right?

You can achieve this using ajax.

You'll need to change your php code to a new file called, for example, load more.php. In this file you'll have php code that will return the data and will return more data if called.

This tutorial worked like a charm form me: https://www.webscodex.com/2020/08/load-more-pagination-with-php-and.html